# WinSCPのコンソールモードで、Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available

Tags: windows, winscp

**WinSCPコンソールモードで下記エラーとなります**

```
winscp> open IPアドレス
```

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server
>   sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

※GUIでは接続出来るのですが…

---

**Q.コンソールモードでの鍵認証設定はどうしたら良いでしょうか？**
・GUIでは、以前から使用している鍵パスを指定しているのですが、コーンソールモードの場合はどう指定するのでしょうか？
・鍵をWinSCPのPUTTYで作り直す？？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/privatekey` オプションで指定します。

例: `winscp.exe scp://test@example.com:2222 /privatekey=mykey.ppk`

[コマンドラインオプション - WinSCP Wiki - WinSCP - OSDN](https://ja.osdn.net/projects/winscp/wiki/commandline)

Comment: 無事に接続することができました

Answer (score 1):

```
winscp> help open
```

と打つと接続方法詳細なヘルプが表示されます。鍵パスの設定方法もそちらに記述されています。